# square rotates by clicking the button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could somebody help me to make this square rotate after clicking the button in javascript? I am very beginner, have absolutely no clue. Maybe my css is not good enough, so I cannot find a solution in js?
All I can do is declare variables, that addEventListner should look like ("click", function()).
I can imagine function should contain initial position of this square (0), then add, for example 10deg to this initial position... And now I stuck.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Powiększ</title>
    <style>
        button {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 50px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }

        .square {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #000;
            position: fixed;
            top: calc(50% - 50px);
            left: calc(50% - 50px);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Obróć</button>
    <div class="square"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please show us the JavaScript that you have tried so far.

Comment: Ii did basics...
https://jsfiddle.net/kjgxn8dq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Powiększ</title>
 <style>
  button {
   padding: 10px;
   font-size: 50px;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 2px solid black;
  }

  .square {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #000;
   position: fixed;
   top: calc(50% - 50px);
   left: calc(50% - 50px);
   -moz-transition: transform 1s;
   -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
   transition: transform 1s;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Obróć</button>
 <div class="square"></div>

 <script>
  var initioalRv = 20;
  function myFunction() {
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.transform = `rotate(${initioalRv}deg)`;
   }
   initioalRv += 20;
  }
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This solevs your problem. I changed your code a bit

1. Added `onCLick` to `button`.
2. Add some css to animate the rotation.
3. Added the `javascript` part.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById('square').style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Powiększ</title>
  <style>
    button {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 50px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
    
    .square {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #000;
      position: fixed;
      top: calc(50% - 50px);
      left: calc(50% - 50px);
      transition: all 2s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn">Obróć</button>
  <div id="square" class="square"></div>

</body>

</html>
```